# Failed to acquire connection SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-job

I am executing a SSIS package from SQL job. I am getting following error time to time.

> Execute SQL Task:Error: Failed to acquire connection "<>".
> Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the
> right permissions on this connection.

When I restart the SQL server agent it works fine again. I am using proxy account to execute the SSIS package from SQL job.
The error is not occurring every time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSIS Failed to acquire connection. Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937044/ssis-failed-to-acquire-connection-connection-may-not-be-configured-correctly-or)